# How to get the abstract model in smtlib2 format or z3 expressions from Solidity SMTChecker?

Tags: solidity, smtchecker, formal-verification

I want to get the abstract model in smtlib2 format or as Z3 expressions created by the SMTChecker. However, i cannot find any compiler switch or something to get the model. The SMTChecker documentation mentions that "smtlib2: outputs SMT/Horn queries in the smtlib2 format." It has not worked for me so far. Maybe i am overlooking something.

Example contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Overflow {
    uint immutable x;
    uint immutable y;

    function add(uint x_, uint y_) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return x_ + y_;
    }

    constructor(uint x_, uint y_) {
        (x, y) = (x_, y_);
    }

    function stateAdd() public view returns (uint) {
        return add(x, y);
    }
}
```

I compile the given contract using the following cmd

```
solc Overflow.sol --model-checker-solvers "z3,smtlib2" --model-checker-engine chc --model-checker-targets overflow
```

I get the following output

```
Warning: CHC: Overflow (resulting value larger than 2**256 - 1) happens here.
Counterexample:
x = 1, y = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
 = 0

Transaction trace:
Overflow.constructor(1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935)
State: x = 1, y = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
Overflow.stateAdd()
    Overflow.add(1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935) -- internal call
 --> o.sol:9:20:
  |
9 |             return x_ + y_;
  |                    ^^^^^^^
```

But i do not get the abstract model created by the SMTChecker. Any ideas how I can get the model?